# Write VARBINARY values into a NVARCHAR column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I use this stored procedure to hash and write a password into a SQL Server table.

```
DECLARE @PassWord as nvarchar(2000) = 'PSW'
...

DECLARE @MD5Password nvarchar(2000);
SELECT @MD5Password = CONVERT(nvarchar(2000),@Password);
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', @MD5Password );  
SET @MD5Password = HASHBYTES('MD5', @MD5Password )

INSERT INTO [MyDataBase].[MyDatatable] (Column1)
VALUES (@MD5Password)
```

The type of `Column1` is `nvarchar(2000)`.

When I use this code to write a password in MyDatatable, the result is not that I expected, it's write like Chinese characters.

I know it's because the conversion from `varbinary` (type Of `@MD5Password`) to `nvarchar`, but I don't know how I have to do to write the good values in Mydatatable?

Can you help please?
Thanks

Comment: Uh, can I ask why you don't make the column varbinary?

Comment: Hi, @Aaron. Because the column was created by an other soft who needs nvarchar for this column.

Comment: Well the other software should not be reading the password, never mind converting it to plain text before doing so. What's the point of hashing it if you're just going to convert it to a string and pass it to the application? The application should take the password the user supplied, hash that, and compare it to the hashed password you have stored. Once it is stored there should be absolutely no reason anyone should ever be converting it back to plain text. What you're trying to do sounds like another Adobe debacle waiting to happen.

Comment: Storing varbinary into nvarchar is just asking for trouble. Are you positive all the chain consuming the values is proofed against [the UTF-16 surrogates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF) (nvarchar is UCS-2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're locked into this specific security implementation by a vendor... if not you need to reevaluate several things, such as the specific hashing algorithm you're using, and the practice of salting your hashes.

So if you are in fact locked into this implementation, my understanding that you're looking to essentially convert a `varbinary` value to a hex string... potentially for the purposes of generating password hashes from your database instead of your application?

[In SQL Server 2005 and onward, you can use xquery to accomplish this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx):

```
DECLARE @Password NVARCHAR(20) = 'PSW'

DECLARE @Hash VARBINARY(16)
DECLARE @HashString VARCHAR(34)

SET @Hash = HASHBYTES('MD5', @Password );  
SET @HashString = '0x' + CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@Hash") )', 'VARCHAR(32)');

SELECT @Hash
SELECT @HashString
```

Before SQL Server 2005, you would have to rely on undocumented system stored procedures, but this is discouraged as [Paul White describes in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46920/3996).

Comment: Thanks @MichealFredrickson. Effectively I'm locked in a specific security implementation. Thank you for your understanding and your answer. It's work like I expected.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in documentation that hashbytes returns a varbinary value. Why is not your column varbinary? And let me ask, why you want a readable hashed password anyway?

If you need it that way just use cast

```
DECLARE @Valor VARBINARY(20)
SET @Valor = CAST('1235667' AS VARBINARY(20))
SELECT @Valor, CAST(@Valor AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Comment: I know HASHBYTES returns a varbinary value.  
I explain in my last comment why I can change the column type. I want a readable hashed password for the other soft can read the column value.

Comment: I started to write before that comments comes in and edited answer after it.

Comment: This won't work when using the output from `HASHBYTES`. It won't convert to the desired hex string, and instead returns `îuzR^Qû}HP=<U§X`.

Comment: Thanks Michael for pointing it. The odd thing is OP need to output that value as a string when for any password purpose all is need is to  hash the user input to compare it with whatever is persisted.